# Salt: Call Execution Module passing parameter value from Pillar data

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to execute a Salt Execution Module, let's say 'svn.update'.

I would prefer *not* to pass the SVN username and password in the command line. That data is already stored in Pillar data available to the target minions.

How can I tell the execution module to get the values for those parameters from the minion's Pillar data?

Something kind of like this (which of course doesn't work):

```
$ sudo salt minionid svn.update cwd=/path/to/sandbox username='pillar.get svn:username' password='pillar.get svn:password'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do following from a state file to call execution module with pillars,

```
{% set svn_update = salt['svn'].update(cwd='/path/to/sandbox', username=pillar['svn']['username'], password=pillar['svn']['password'] %}
```

Comment: Thanks. Of course, if a state is involved I would use the svn state module directly instead of the execution module.